# Playground.js Not Rendering

Tags: javascript

I went through the first two tutorials on the Playground.js [website](http://playgroundjs.com/intro/getting-started), but the rectangle is not rendering the rectangle. Here is the directory structure:

```
index.html
scripts
---main.js
---playground.js
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Simple Game</title></head>

    <body>

        <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/playground.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
var app = playground({
    render: function() {
        this.layer.clear("#000088");
        this.layer.fillStyle("#ffffff");
        this.layer.fillRect(32, 32, 64, 64);
    }
});
```

playground.js is the downloaded file from the website.

What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Switch your main and playground script tags. The order matters

Comment: It worked! Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your main and playground script tags. The order matters:

```
    <script src="scripts/playground.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```